# Setting background on ImageButton doesn't work

Tags: android, image, button, selector, imagebutton

I have an ImageButton and I wanted to be able to see a color when I clicked on it. I added a background, and used the same listselector I use for all my listviews, but it doesn't show anything when I click the ImageButton.

Here is the ImageButton xml

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button_biomes"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/biome" 
    android:background="@drawable/listselector"/>
```

And this is the listselector drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_enabled="true" 
     android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/actionbar" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
     android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/actionbar" />
    <item
     android:drawable="@color/android:transparent" />
</selector>
```

If anyone could help me It'd be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you remove the `android:src` from the ImageButton ? Also try to define a different `drawable` for each `item` rather than different `color`. So you can try something like `<item android:state_enabled="true" 
     android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/SOME_OTHER_DRAWABLE_OF_THAT_COLOR" />` . See if it creates any difference .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that your image takes up entire space and doesn't show the background. Here, image and background are two different things, so do not expect the src image to be transparent.

Comment: I managed to partially achieve what I wanted. I switched the android:src and android:background so that the listselector was the src and the image was the background. Although this works, my question is, how can I make the listselector color (Green) translucent so I can still see the image when I press on the ImageButton?

Comment: then remove the background tag and add the selector.xml to src tag. Next up, create two images, one normal and another with opacity 50-70% in photoshop and add these images as drawables in your selector.